# Cygnus: Unable to deliver event. close() called when transaction is OPEN - you must either commit or rollback first

Tags: apache-kafka, fiware, fiware-cygnus

I've installed Fiware Orion (v 1.13.0), Fiware  Cygnus (2.8.0) and Kafka in order to send data from Orion to Kafka via Cygnus.

I've used the conf file suggested [in the cygnus documentation](https://fiware-cygnus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cygnus-ngsi/integration/orion_cygnus_kafka/index.html#section4)

```
cygnus-ngsi.sources =http-source
cygnus-ngsi.sinks =kafka-sink
cygnus-ngsi.channels =kafka-channel

cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.channels = kafka-channel
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.type = org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.port = 5050
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.NGSIRestHandler
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler.notification_target = /notify
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler.default_service = def_serv
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler.default_service_path = /def_servpath
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler.events_ttl = 2
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors = ts gi
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors.ts.type = timestamp
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.NGSIGroupingInterceptor$Builder
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.grouping_rules_conf_file = /opt/apache-flume/conf/grouping_rules.conf


cygnus-ngsi.channels.kafka-channel.type = memory
cygnus-ngsi.channels.kafka-channel.capacity = 1000
cygnus-ngsi.channels.kafka-channel.trasactionCapacity = 100

cygnus-ngsi.sinks.kafka-sink.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSIKafkaSink
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.kafka-sink.channel = kafka-channel
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.kafka-sink.enable_grouping = false
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.kafka-sink.data_model = dm-by-entity
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.kafka-sink.broker_list = 192.168.1.142:9092
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.kafka-sink.zookeeper_endpoint = 192.168.1.142:2181
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.kafka-sink.batch_size = 1
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.kafka-sink.batch_timeout = 10
```

Everything is up using Docker swarm

```
ID             NAME              MODE         REPLICAS   IMAGE                       PORTS
c195zwpxparu   cygnus_cygnus     replicated   1/1        fiware/cygnus-ngsi:latest   *:5050->5050/tcp, *:5055->5055/tcp, *:5080->5080/tcp
pzjvud4q4ibc   kafka_kafka       replicated   1/1        bitnami/kafka:2             *:9092->9092/tcp
bpyaz4jphuhh   kafka_zookeeper   replicated   1/1        bitnami/zookeeper:3         *:2181->2181/tcp
jk4po3ofs3bm   orion_mongodb     replicated   1/1        mongo:3.6.5
mlknk6j7y5kd   orion_orion       replicated   1/1        fiware/orion:1.13.0         *:1026->1026/tcp
```

This is my docker-compose.yml about cygnus

```
version: "3"
services:

  cygnus:
    image: fiware/cygnus-ngsi
    ports:
      - "5050:5050"
      - "5055:5055"
      - "5080:5080"
    volumes:
      - ./conf/agent.conf:/opt/apache-flume/conf/agent.conf
    environment:
      - CYGNUS_SKIP_CONF_GENERATION=true
      - CYGNUS_MULTIAGENT=false
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: any
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 120s
  
networks:
  default:
    driver: overlay
    driver_opts:
      com.docker.network.driver.mtu: 1400
```

When the notification arrives from Orion to localhost:5050/notify, on Cygnus console this error appears

```
cygnus_cygnus.1.wfg7cz8r3e1v@docker-desktop    | time=2021-04-16T10:12:13.774Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=36cccd7a-9e9c-11eb-8e44-02420a000004; cbnotif=2 | trans=a6fe0530-c653-4e19-828a-6
7ec45b37a96 | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=run | msg=org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner[158] : Unable to deliver event. Exception follows.
cygnus_cygnus.1.wfg7cz8r3e1v@docker-desktop    | java.lang.IllegalStateException: close() called when transaction is OPEN - you must either commit or rollback first
cygnus_cygnus.1.wfg7cz8r3e1v@docker-desktop    |        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:172)
cygnus_cygnus.1.wfg7cz8r3e1v@docker-desktop    |        at org.apache.flume.channel.BasicTransactionSemantics.close(BasicTransactionSemantics.java:179)
cygnus_cygnus.1.wfg7cz8r3e1v@docker-desktop    |        at com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink.processNewBatches(NGSISink.java:646)
cygnus_cygnus.1.wfg7cz8r3e1v@docker-desktop    |        at com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink.process(NGSISink.java:373)
cygnus_cygnus.1.wfg7cz8r3e1v@docker-desktop    |        at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor.process(DefaultSinkProcessor.java:67)
cygnus_cygnus.1.wfg7cz8r3e1v@docker-desktop    |        at org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run(SinkRunner.java:145)
cygnus_cygnus.1.wfg7cz8r3e1v@docker-desktop    |        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
cygnus_cygnus.1.wfg7cz8r3e1v@docker-desktop    | time=2021-04-16T10:12:18.778Z | lvl=INFO | corr=36cccd7a-9e9c-11eb-8e44-02420a000004; cbnotif=2 | trans=a6fe0530-c653-4e19-828a-67
ec45b37a96 | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=processNewBatches | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink[643] : Rollback transaction by Exception  (begin() calle
d when transaction is OPEN!)
```

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

The current cygnus [release](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/releases) is indeed 2.8.0., but Orion 1.13.0 is several years old and unlikely to align with the latest Cygnus build.

The current Orion [release](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/releases) is 3.0.0. Try using that instead.

A basic working example with latest Orion and latest Cygnus can be found [here](https://github.com/FIWARE/tutorials.Historic-Context-Flume) within the [Step-by-Step Tutorials for NGSI-v2](https://fiware-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: I've tried using both Orion 2.6.1 and 3.0.0 but the problem remains. There is no reference to Kafka in your links. I need to send NGSI data from Orion to Kafka. I followed this guide (
https://fiware-cygnus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cygnus-ngsi/integration/orion_cygnus_kafka/index.html), but I'm afraid it's outdated documentation. Is kafka still supported by Cygnus?

Comment: Even in the case it doesn't solve your problem, I'd suggest to follow Jason's recommendation and upgrade Orion to 3.0.0. If at the end this is somekind of issue in the software, that issue should be debugged and fixed in latests version.

Comment: @fgalan I've tried using both Orion 2.6.1 and 3.0.0 but the problem remains.

Comment: There now appears to be an [open issue](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/issues/2014) about this, so it looks unlikely that this question can be successfully answered without changes in the underlying software.